# Craft 3 This field’s Volume configuration is invalid

Tags: matrix

I just upgraded a Craft 2 site to 3, and am getting this error from one of my matrix blocks.

```
This field’s Volume configuration is invalid
```

This what it looks like in backend:
[image]

Oddly enough, I went into settings and resaved the field, not touching anything else, and now I can atleast see the images:

[image]

However, I cant save the entry now, and am greeted with the same error:

```
This field’s Volume configuration is invalid
```

** Updated Volume Assets Screenshot **
[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at your field and at the selected volume in that field. Without knowing your volume settings we can't provide much help. The error already states that the volume is not correct

Comment: Yeah please share a screenshot of your volume settings so we can see what's going on there. Most likely you've got something incorrect in the volume settings, hence the errors.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot. These are the only fields that are giving me a problem on the entire site. Everything else works fine. I have other matrix blocks that utilize images as well, and they are not broken.

Comment: Seems like your `$defaultUploadLocationSource` or `singleUploadLocationSource` is not set. Please take a look at your field settings